# PHP FQL Query gives Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, facebook-fql

Why can't I return a fql query like this? There seems to be tons of different ways and none of them work, each one returns a different error?

```
require_once("facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'XXXXXXXX';
$config[‘secret’] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token='.$cookie['access_token']));


foreach($user[data] as $friend){
    $fql="select name from user where uid =".$friend['id'];
    $param=array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $fql,'callback' => '');
    $fqlResult=$facebook->api($param);
    }
print_r($fqlResult);
```

This way gives this error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/rig/public_html/FB/Q.php on line 13

Comment: Hi newbie, which line is line 13?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the actual structure of the json string, my best guess is :-

```
foreach($user[data]
```

change to

```
foreach($user->data
```

Answer (score 0):

> try `var_dump($user);` Then you got json structure and can do easily